# Capture UIImageView context

Tags: ios4

I am trying capture UIIMage with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext();` but my code capture the whole screen then save it into photo library ...

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I just want capture my UIImageView things on it ! ...
any suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it ! :

> UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.bounds.size);
>     [image.layer
>   renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];